# Adding buildpath of existing project to a new project

Tags: java, eclipse, buildpath

I have two projects in Eclipse's workspace Project A & Project B.

I want to add Project B to A's buildpath but no matter what I do it doesn't work. I've looked it look and none of the answers work for me. Although exporting B as a jar and adding the jar to the buildpath works I will need to update B's code and I do not want to have to constantly export it as jar everytime.

I've tried adding B as a class folder but it fails to work. In the jar `import bproj.BMain;` works but as a class folder it does not.

How can I add B to A's buildpath?

Comment: This question is crisp clear.Why flags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Eclipse Mars, open any file from Project B and on the menu, go to **Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Projects > Add**

From there, you:

> can add B to A's buildpath

by selecting Project A from the list.

Nice username, by the way :-)

Comment: I swear I tried that! But yeah it worked this time... thanks.

Comment: Awesome, glad to have helped.